# Unseen directory in Quasar doc

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

For Quasar doc here:
https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/tree/dev/docs

The lines below
https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/dev/docs/quasar.conf.js#L5
https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/dev/docs/quasar.conf.js#L57
are pointing to 'quasar/dist' folder, such folder doesn't exist yet, how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked my quasar project (v2).

You first need to run `npm install` in your quasar directory.

Then I got the mentioned file under
`app\node_modules\quasar\dist\ssr-directives\index.js`

This is the content:

```
const noopTransform = () => ({ props: [] })
module.exports = {
  'close-popup': noopTransform,
  'intersection': noopTransform,
  'morph': require('./Morph.js'),
  'mutation': noopTransform,
  'ripple': noopTransform,
  'scroll': noopTransform,
  'scroll-fire': noopTransform,
  'touch-hold': noopTransform,
  'touch-pan': noopTransform,
  'touch-repeat': noopTransform,
  'touch-swipe': noopTransform
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pointing to quasar.conf.js, but it would be necessary to quasar.config.js